# Lovers and haters via the Jordan curve theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology

In J. Roe's *Winding Around* and V. Arnold's *Ordinary Differential Equations* there is a beautiful story attributed to N. Konstantinov:

*A pair of lovers travels from city $A$ to city $B$ via two different roads. If the distance between them is at least 10 kilometers, then they die.
There is also a pair of haters – one travelling from $A$ to $B$ and the other travelling from $B$ to $A$. If the distance between them is at most 10 kilometers, then they die.
Prove that the tragedy is inevitable.*

Putting it rigorously, one measures the motion of each pair by continuous paths into the square and proves the following theorem:

> **Theorem** Let $f, g\colon [0, 1]\to [0, 1]\times[0, 1]$ be continuous maps, such that $f(0) = (0, 0),\,f(1)= (1,1)$ and $g(0) = (0, 1),\,g(1) = (1, 0)$. Then $f(x)=g(y)$ for some $x, y\in [0, 1]$.

This is [a special case of Exercise 0.5](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/266477/551592) of J. Rotman's *Algebraic topology*, with Bombyx mori's solution via Brouwer fixed point theorem. Another beautiful solution is possible – in Exercise 3.6.5 of *Winding around*, the author hints to close the image of $g$ to a loop:
[image: Closing the image of g to a loop]
and then says to use the properties of winding number.

Although both solutions – by Brouwer fixed point theorem or by winding number – work beautifully, I am looking for a third one:

> Is there a solution that uses the [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem)?

Surely, if $g$ is injective, the closed loop is homeomorphic to the circle and we immediately get the claim. I however don't know whether this can be generalized to an arbitrary $g$.

Comment: I believe the theorem is wrong as stated. It should be $f(x)=g(y)$.

Comment: For the proof via Jordan, replace g (really, its image) by $\tilde{g}=\{(x.y)\in [0,1]^2 : \text{line between } (x,0) \text{ and } (x,y)\text{  doesn't intersect } g\}$  and prove that (1) the boundary of $\tilde{g}$ is a subset of that of $g$ and (2) $\tilde{g}$ has a continuous injective parameterization. This doesn't feel super elegant, so I'll leave it as a comment and hope someone gives a proper answer

Comment: @Bananach Thank you, I fixed it :) Your solution looks slick, I'll analyse it carefully!

Comment: On second reading, I think my solution is wrong ;)